# Are you using a Sharp PN-K321 at 60Hz with a Late 2013 Mac Pro?

Tags: hardware, mac-pro, displayport, display

According to [Apple's KBase article on "Using 4K displays"](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6008), the Sharp PN-K321 monitor is supported at 60Hz in MST mode if you're connected via mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort.

I've ordered a [StarTech mDP-DP cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003TSTDI0) as Amazon's comments indicate that it works well (or well enough), just wondering if anyone has any experience with this or similar products.

Namely, do you have problems waking the Mac Pro from sleep?  Does the display properly wake up?  Do you notice any flickering or lag using Photoshop or any other 2D or 3D applications?

The Pro is already updated to OS X 10.9.3; haven't checked yet whether the Sharp display is on the [latest firmware](https://www.sharpusa.com/ForBusiness/PresentationProducts/ProfessionalLCDMonitors/PNK321.aspx?view=software) (v11301118).

Comment: do you experience any of the symptoms or just asking a hypothetical question

Comment: Using the Pro with the Sharp over HDMI, my users are reporting noticeable flicker in Photoshop CS6.

Answer (score 1):

The StarTech cables work perfectly, all that was required to enable 60Hz was to use the display's onscreen controls to enable MST mode.  Restart the display and voila.

Definitely noticeable improvement in scrolling through large Photoshop and Illustrator files.